# Notepad++ add characters until size in each line

Tags: notepad++

I have a file with many lines of differet sizes and I would like to add some period signs until each line has 30 characters (my text + periods). How can I do that in a simple way?

Ex. before:

```
My text
My long text
```

After:

```
My text.......................
My long text..................
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In two steps with regex replace (for all lines, restart at the begin)

```
substitute "$" by "............ ..."
substitute "^(.{30}).*$" by "$1"
```

- `.` any character
- `\.` the dot itself, needs escaping
- `^` begin of line
- `$` end of line
- `( )` a numbered group referred by
- `$1` the first group
- ...`{30}` upto thirty repetitions of the prior subpattern
- ...`*` zero or more of the prior subpattern

In the first step one appends to every line thirty period signs.

In the second step one replaces the entire line from begin `^` to end `$` with the first thirty any characters `.{30}`.

Comment: Thanks, @Joop Eggen! Exactly what I needed! Just didn't understand the explanation... Could you be more clear?